# Candlestick-Chart with title on x axis

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts, candlestick-chart

I wanna use the Candlestick-Chart from amCharts with a title on the X-axis.
(Like the title on the Y-axis.)

Y-axis Example:

```
"valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "left",
     "title": "That is the title on the y axis"
  } ]
```

Example: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/candlestick-chart/

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Simply add [`title`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#title) property to `categoryAxis`:

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "parseDates": true,
  "title": "That is the title on the X-axis"
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataDateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD",
  "valueAxes": [ {
    "position": "left",
      "title": "That is the title on the Y-axis"
  } ],
  "graphs": [ {
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonText": "Open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>Low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>High:<b>[[high]]</b><br>Close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>",
    "closeField": "close",
    "fillColors": "#7f8da9",
    "highField": "high",
    "lineColor": "#7f8da9",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lowField": "low",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "negativeFillColors": "#db4c3c",
    "negativeLineColor": "#db4c3c",
    "openField": "open",
    "title": "Price:",
    "type": "candlestick",
    "valueField": "close"
  } ],
  "chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "graphType": "line",
    "scrollbarHeight": 30
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
     "title": "That is the title on the X-axis"
  },
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "date": "2011-08-01",
    "open": "136.65",
    "high": "136.96",
    "low": "134.15",
    "close": "136.49"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-02",
    "open": "135.26",
    "high": "135.95",
    "low": "131.50",
    "close": "131.85"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-05",
    "open": "132.90",
    "high": "135.27",
    "low": "128.30",
    "close": "135.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-06",
    "open": "134.94",
    "high": "137.24",
    "low": "132.63",
    "close": "135.03"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-07",
    "open": "136.76",
    "high": "136.86",
    "low": "132.00",
    "close": "134.01"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-08",
    "open": "131.11",
    "high": "133.00",
    "low": "125.09",
    "close": "126.39"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-09",
    "open": "123.12",
    "high": "127.75",
    "low": "120.30",
    "close": "125.00"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-12",
    "open": "128.32",
    "high": "129.35",
    "low": "126.50",
    "close": "127.79"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-13",
    "open": "128.29",
    "high": "128.30",
    "low": "123.71",
    "close": "124.03"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-14",
    "open": "122.74",
    "high": "124.86",
    "low": "119.65",
    "close": "119.90"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-15",
    "open": "117.01",
    "high": "118.50",
    "low": "111.62",
    "close": "117.05"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-16",
    "open": "122.01",
    "high": "123.50",
    "low": "119.82",
    "close": "122.06"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-19",
    "open": "123.96",
    "high": "124.50",
    "low": "120.50",
    "close": "122.22"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-20",
    "open": "122.21",
    "high": "128.96",
    "low": "121.00",
    "close": "127.57"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-21",
    "open": "131.22",
    "high": "132.75",
    "low": "130.33",
    "close": "132.51"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-22",
    "open": "133.09",
    "high": "133.34",
    "low": "129.76",
    "close": "131.07"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-23",
    "open": "130.53",
    "high": "135.37",
    "low": "129.81",
    "close": "135.30"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-26",
    "open": "133.39",
    "high": "134.66",
    "low": "132.10",
    "close": "132.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-27",
    "open": "130.99",
    "high": "132.41",
    "low": "126.63",
    "close": "126.82"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-28",
    "open": "129.88",
    "high": "134.18",
    "low": "129.54",
    "close": "134.08"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-29",
    "open": "132.67",
    "high": "138.25",
    "low": "132.30",
    "close": "136.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-08-30",
    "open": "139.49",
    "high": "139.65",
    "low": "137.41",
    "close": "138.48"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-03",
    "open": "139.94",
    "high": "145.73",
    "low": "139.84",
    "close": "144.16"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-04",
    "open": "144.97",
    "high": "145.84",
    "low": "136.10",
    "close": "136.76"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-05",
    "open": "135.56",
    "high": "137.57",
    "low": "132.71",
    "close": "135.01"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-06",
    "open": "132.01",
    "high": "132.30",
    "low": "130.00",
    "close": "131.77"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-09",
    "open": "136.99",
    "high": "138.04",
    "low": "133.95",
    "close": "136.71"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-10",
    "open": "137.90",
    "high": "138.30",
    "low": "133.75",
    "close": "135.49"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-11",
    "open": "135.99",
    "high": "139.40",
    "low": "135.75",
    "close": "136.85"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-12",
    "open": "138.83",
    "high": "139.00",
    "low": "136.65",
    "close": "137.20"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-13",
    "open": "136.57",
    "high": "138.98",
    "low": "136.20",
    "close": "138.81"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-16",
    "open": "138.99",
    "high": "140.59",
    "low": "137.60",
    "close": "138.41"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-17",
    "open": "139.06",
    "high": "142.85",
    "low": "137.83",
    "close": "140.92"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-18",
    "open": "143.02",
    "high": "143.16",
    "low": "139.40",
    "close": "140.77"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-19",
    "open": "140.15",
    "high": "141.79",
    "low": "139.32",
    "close": "140.31"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-20",
    "open": "141.14",
    "high": "144.65",
    "low": "140.31",
    "close": "144.15"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-23",
    "open": "146.73",
    "high": "149.85",
    "low": "146.65",
    "close": "148.28"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-24",
    "open": "146.84",
    "high": "153.22",
    "low": "146.82",
    "close": "153.18"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-25",
    "open": "154.47",
    "high": "155.00",
    "low": "151.25",
    "close": "152.77"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-26",
    "open": "153.77",
    "high": "154.52",
    "low": "152.32",
    "close": "154.50"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-27",
    "open": "153.44",
    "high": "154.60",
    "low": "152.75",
    "close": "153.47"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-09-30",
    "open": "154.63",
    "high": "157.41",
    "low": "152.93",
    "close": "156.34"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-01",
    "open": "156.55",
    "high": "158.59",
    "low": "155.89",
    "close": "158.45"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-02",
    "open": "157.78",
    "high": "159.18",
    "low": "157.01",
    "close": "157.92"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-03",
    "open": "158.00",
    "high": "158.08",
    "low": "153.50",
    "close": "156.24"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-04",
    "open": "158.37",
    "high": "161.58",
    "low": "157.70",
    "close": "161.45"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-07",
    "open": "163.49",
    "high": "167.91",
    "low": "162.97",
    "close": "167.91"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-08",
    "open": "170.20",
    "high": "171.11",
    "low": "166.68",
    "close": "167.86"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-09",
    "open": "167.55",
    "high": "167.88",
    "low": "165.60",
    "close": "166.79"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-10",
    "open": "169.49",
    "high": "171.88",
    "low": "153.21",
    "close": "162.23"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-11",
    "open": "163.01",
    "high": "167.28",
    "low": "161.80",
    "close": "167.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-14",
    "open": "167.98",
    "high": "169.57",
    "low": "163.50",
    "close": "166.98"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-15",
    "open": "165.54",
    "high": "170.18",
    "low": "165.15",
    "close": "169.58"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-16",
    "open": "172.69",
    "high": "173.04",
    "low": "169.18",
    "close": "172.75"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-17",
    "open": "171.50",
    "high": "174.19",
    "low": "171.05",
    "close": "173.50"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-18",
    "open": "174.24",
    "high": "174.63",
    "low": "170.00",
    "close": "170.42"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-21",
    "open": "170.35",
    "high": "174.90",
    "low": "169.96",
    "close": "174.36"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-22",
    "open": "188.56",
    "high": "188.60",
    "low": "182.76",
    "close": "186.16"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-23",
    "open": "185.81",
    "high": "187.21",
    "low": "179.24",
    "close": "185.93"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-24",
    "open": "184.87",
    "high": "185.90",
    "low": "181.66",
    "close": "182.78"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-25",
    "open": "185.29",
    "high": "185.37",
    "low": "182.88",
    "close": "184.70"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-28",
    "open": "185.45",
    "high": "186.59",
    "low": "184.70",
    "close": "185.09"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-29",
    "open": "186.18",
    "high": "189.37",
    "low": "184.73",
    "close": "187.00"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-30",
    "open": "187.63",
    "high": "190.12",
    "low": "184.95",
    "close": "189.95"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-10-31",
    "open": "188.60",
    "high": "190.10",
    "low": "180.00",
    "close": "187.44"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-01",
    "open": "189.21",
    "high": "189.44",
    "low": "183.49",
    "close": "187.87"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-04",
    "open": "185.29",
    "high": "188.96",
    "low": "184.24",
    "close": "186.18"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-05",
    "open": "187.05",
    "high": "192.00",
    "low": "185.27",
    "close": "191.79"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-06",
    "open": "190.61",
    "high": "192.68",
    "low": "186.13",
    "close": "186.30"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-07",
    "open": "186.67",
    "high": "186.90",
    "low": "167.77",
    "close": "175.47"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-08",
    "open": "171.15",
    "high": "175.12",
    "low": "165.21",
    "close": "165.37"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-11",
    "open": "165.28",
    "high": "167.70",
    "low": "150.63",
    "close": "153.76"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-12",
    "open": "160.85",
    "high": "170.98",
    "low": "153.76",
    "close": "169.96"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-13",
    "open": "177.16",
    "high": "177.57",
    "low": "163.74",
    "close": "166.11"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-14",
    "open": "166.39",
    "high": "169.59",
    "low": "160.30",
    "close": "164.30"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-15",
    "open": "165.30",
    "high": "167.02",
    "low": "159.33",
    "close": "166.39"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-18",
    "open": "166.10",
    "high": "168.20",
    "low": "162.10",
    "close": "163.95"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-19",
    "open": "165.67",
    "high": "171.79",
    "low": "163.53",
    "close": "168.85"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-20",
    "open": "165.84",
    "high": "172.35",
    "low": "164.67",
    "close": "168.46"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-22",
    "open": "172.00",
    "high": "172.05",
    "low": "169.75",
    "close": "171.54"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-25",
    "open": "173.59",
    "high": "177.27",
    "low": "172.35",
    "close": "172.54"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-26",
    "open": "175.22",
    "high": "175.79",
    "low": "170.01",
    "close": "174.81"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-27",
    "open": "176.82",
    "high": "180.60",
    "low": "175.35",
    "close": "180.22"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-28",
    "open": "179.43",
    "high": "185.17",
    "low": "179.15",
    "close": "184.29"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-11-29",
    "open": "187.34",
    "high": "187.70",
    "low": "179.70",
    "close": "182.22"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-02",
    "open": "181.86",
    "high": "184.14",
    "low": "177.70",
    "close": "178.86"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-03",
    "open": "177.15",
    "high": "180.90",
    "low": "176.99",
    "close": "179.81"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-04",
    "open": "182.89",
    "high": "186.00",
    "low": "182.41",
    "close": "185.50"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-05",
    "open": "186.19",
    "high": "190.10",
    "low": "186.12",
    "close": "189.95"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-06",
    "open": "190.54",
    "high": "194.99",
    "low": "188.04",
    "close": "194.30"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-09",
    "open": "193.59",
    "high": "195.66",
    "low": "192.69",
    "close": "194.21"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-10",
    "open": "194.75",
    "high": "196.83",
    "low": "187.39",
    "close": "188.54"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-11",
    "open": "193.44",
    "high": "194.48",
    "low": "185.76",
    "close": "190.86"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-12",
    "open": "190.19",
    "high": "192.12",
    "low": "187.82",
    "close": "191.83"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-13",
    "open": "190.37",
    "high": "193.20",
    "low": "189.54",
    "close": "190.39"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-16",
    "open": "190.72",
    "high": "192.65",
    "low": "182.98",
    "close": "184.40"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-17",
    "open": "186.52",
    "high": "187.33",
    "low": "178.60",
    "close": "182.98"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-18",
    "open": "182.98",
    "high": "184.64",
    "low": "180.90",
    "close": "183.12"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-19",
    "open": "185.43",
    "high": "187.83",
    "low": "183.33",
    "close": "187.21"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-20",
    "open": "190.12",
    "high": "193.91",
    "low": "189.89",
    "close": "193.91"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-23",
    "open": "195.03",
    "high": "199.33",
    "low": "194.79",
    "close": "198.80"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-25",
    "open": "199.01",
    "high": "200.96",
    "low": "196.82",
    "close": "198.95"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-26",
    "open": "198.95",
    "high": "202.96",
    "low": "197.80",
    "close": "198.57"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-27",
    "open": "200.59",
    "high": "201.56",
    "low": "196.88",
    "close": "199.83"
  }, {
    "date": "2011-12-30",
    "open": "199.50",
    "high": "200.50",
    "low": "197.75",
    "close": "198.08"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-01",
    "open": "199.27",
    "high": "200.26",
    "low": "192.55",
    "close": "194.84"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-02",
    "open": "195.41",
    "high": "197.39",
    "low": "192.69",
    "close": "194.93"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-03",
    "open": "191.45",
    "high": "193.00",
    "low": "178.89",
    "close": "180.05"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-06",
    "open": "181.25",
    "high": "183.60",
    "low": "170.23",
    "close": "177.64"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-07",
    "open": "180.14",
    "high": "182.46",
    "low": "170.80",
    "close": "171.25"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-08",
    "open": "171.30",
    "high": "179.50",
    "low": "168.30",
    "close": "179.40"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-09",
    "open": "177.58",
    "high": "181.00",
    "low": "175.41",
    "close": "178.02"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-10",
    "open": "176.00",
    "high": "177.85",
    "low": "170.00",
    "close": "172.69"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-13",
    "open": "177.52",
    "high": "179.42",
    "low": "175.17",
    "close": "178.78"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-14",
    "open": "177.72",
    "high": "179.22",
    "low": "164.66",
    "close": "169.04"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-15",
    "open": "165.23",
    "high": "169.01",
    "low": "156.70",
    "close": "159.64"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-16",
    "open": "161.51",
    "high": "165.36",
    "low": "158.42",
    "close": "160.89"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-17",
    "open": "161.71",
    "high": "165.75",
    "low": "159.61",
    "close": "161.36"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-21",
    "open": "148.06",
    "high": "159.98",
    "low": "146.00",
    "close": "155.64"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-22",
    "open": "136.19",
    "high": "140.00",
    "low": "126.14",
    "close": "139.07"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-23",
    "open": "139.99",
    "high": "140.70",
    "low": "132.01",
    "close": "135.60"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-24",
    "open": "138.99",
    "high": "139.09",
    "low": "129.61",
    "close": "130.01"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-27",
    "open": "128.16",
    "high": "133.20",
    "low": "126.45",
    "close": "130.01"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-28",
    "open": "131.15",
    "high": "132.79",
    "low": "129.05",
    "close": "131.54"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-29",
    "open": "131.37",
    "high": "135.45",
    "low": "130.00",
    "close": "132.18"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-30",
    "open": "129.45",
    "high": "136.65",
    "low": "129.40",
    "close": "135.36"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-01-31",
    "open": "136.24",
    "high": "136.59",
    "low": "132.18",
    "close": "133.75"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-03",
    "open": "134.21",
    "high": "135.90",
    "low": "131.42",
    "close": "131.65"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-04",
    "open": "130.43",
    "high": "134.00",
    "low": "128.90",
    "close": "129.36"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-05",
    "open": "130.83",
    "high": "131.92",
    "low": "121.77",
    "close": "122.00"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-06",
    "open": "119.97",
    "high": "124.78",
    "low": "117.27",
    "close": "121.24"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-07",
    "open": "122.08",
    "high": "125.70",
    "low": "121.60",
    "close": "125.48"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-10",
    "open": "128.01",
    "high": "129.98",
    "low": "127.20",
    "close": "129.45"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-11",
    "open": "130.70",
    "high": "131.00",
    "low": "123.62",
    "close": "124.86"
  }, {
    "date": "2012-02-12",
    "open": "126.68",
    "high": "129.78",
    "low": "125.63",
    "close": "129.40"
  } ]
} );

chart.addListener( "rendered", zoomChart );
zoomChart();

// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
function zoomChart() {
  // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
  chart.zoomToIndexes( chart.dataProvider.length - 10, chart.dataProvider.length - 1 );
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```